# How to include raw data in an R package

Tags: r, dataframe, file, package, roxygen2

I'm working on the final assignment of the course [Building R Packages](https://www.coursera.org/learn/r-packages).

In this assignment, we need to create an R package based on some example functions provided by the instructors. We need to organize and document the package, then make it available on GitHub. My package is called `FARS` and is already available in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/marmello77/FARS).

I'm having trouble with making raw data available with the package. After following the instructions provided in the course's readings and also in chapter 14.3 of the book [Building R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/), the files are still not being recognized.

What did I do so far?

1. Prepared all the package's documentation, including `roxygen2` tags, `DESCRIPTION`, `README.Md`, and `vignette`, following [these steps](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) in addition to instructions provided in the readings and book mentioned;
2. Created a subdirectory named `inst/extdata` in the package's directory;
3. Copied all three example files (`.csv.bz2`) with raw data to `inst/extdata`;
4. Tested the functions using `testthat`;
5. Installed my `FARS` package.

Now I'm trying to check if one of the files is available after installing the package:

```
system.file("extdata", "accident_2013.csv.bz2", 
            package = "FARS", 
            mustWork = TRUE)
```

I get an error message:

```
Error in system.file("extdata", "accident_2013.csv.bz2", package = "FARS",  : 
  no file found
```

These data files need to be available with the package, so the examples provided in the vignette work properly.

Comment: I recommend going to CRAN and downloading the "R-exts.pdf" file, which has detailed instructions on how to do everything when building a package.

Comment: Thank you! I've read this official document too, item "1.1.6 Data in packages". Nevertheless, I didn't find a solution there. It seems I'm following all steps suggested, but the data files are not found anyway.

Comment: I recently completed a package which contained a data directory. Let me dig it up and I'll post the exact folders and the  NameSpace file contents I used.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a "real-life" example, using a simple package I wrote recently.
I have a "data" directory in the build directory.
**EDIT**  To clarify the comments found in R-exts, the  directory tree  `packagename/inst/extdata` is intended for data that your functions call directly, by specifying that directory path.  Since you want to load data into your workspace, use the `data` directory.
My "data" directory contains one file named `preciseNumbersAsChar.r` . That file contains assignments such as

`charE <- {long number string}`

If you read the help page for the command `data`, it explains that files ending in `.r` are `source`d when called.

```
library(FunWithNumbers)
data('preciseNumbersAsChar')  #works
```

Which is to say, the defined objects are now in my environment.

It's worth reading the help page for `data` in detail as different file types are handled slightly differently.

Comment: Thank you very much! This option of properly storing the files in the "data" directory is also working for me. Your example is indeed very helpful and I'll do it your way in my future real-world packages. What I couldn't get to work were the data files from my homework assignment. The example functions provided by the instructors assume you have three specific data files in CSV format. Two of the functions work by renaming those files or reading some of their variables. So I've included these assumptions in the vignette, as well as the source of the files.